# Filtering JSON based on value

Tags: c#, json, deserialization

I have this object and would like to filter it based on the value of customer_email. For example, I only want to return commissions where the customer email is test@test.com. This is a simplified example of what a response would look like. Below is the method where I grab all the data.

```
public RootObject GetData(string customerEmail)
{
    var data = new Commission();
    using (var httpClient = new HttpClient())
    {
            var requestContent = JObject.FromObject(new
            {
                commission_id = data.id,
                customer_email = customerEmail

            }).ToString();

        ......

        RootObject response = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(responseContent);

        return response;
    }
}
```

When I get the response, the information looks like this:

```
{"response":{
    "code":"200",
    "message":"OK: The request was successful. See response body for additional data.",
    "data":{
        "commissions":
        [{
        "commission_id":"12345",
        "customer_email":"test@test.com"
        },
        {
        "commission_id":"67890",
        "customer_email":"fake@fake.com"
        }]
```

Comment: please can you post the code for the RootObject class?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve it using simple LINQ right after serialization of `response` to `RootObject`.

```
return response
        .Response.Data.Commissions
        .Where(commission => commission.CustomerEmail == customerEmail);
```

Answer (score 0):

Then you can use a lambda expression to easily filter the contents of that list.

```
return response.Response.Data.Commissions.Where(c => c.customerEmail==customerEmail);
```

This will return only the instances of `Commission` in the response's `commissions` collection.

A side effect of this solution would be changing the return type of the method from `RootObject` to `IEnumerable<Commission>`. Which would mean that callers of this method would no longer have access to any other data in the response object (besides the commissions data).